# Elasticsearch python API: Delete documents by query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes, pyelasticsearch

I see that the following API will do delete by query in Elasticsearch - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

But I want to do the same with the elastic search bulk API, even though I could use bulk to upload docs using

```
es.bulk(body=json_batch)
```

I am not sure how to invoke delete by query using the python bulk API for Elastic search.

Comment: Without seeing specifics, check out the helpers: http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html

Comment: See: [API of delete_by_query()](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.delete_by_query).

Comment: See: [Delete records from Elasticsearch by query](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17676022/55075)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seeing as how elasticsearch has deprecated the delete by query API. I created [this python script](https://gist.github.com/dforste/db72b1ccd81556f580a0) using the bindings to do the same thing. 
First thing define an ES connection:

```
import elasticsearch
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(['localhost'])
```

Now you can use that to create a query for results you want to delete.

```
search=es.search(
    q='The Query to ES.',
    index="*logstash-*",
    size=10,
    search_type="scan",
    scroll='5m',
)
```

Now you can scroll that query in a loop. Generate our request while we do it.

```
 while True:
    try: 
      # Git the next page of results. 
      scroll=es.scroll( scroll_id=search['_scroll_id'], scroll='5m', )
    # Since scroll throws an error catch it and break the loop. 
    except elasticsearch.exceptions.NotFoundError: 
      break 
    # We have results initialize the bulk variable. 
    bulk = ""
    for result in scroll['hits']['hits']:
      bulk = bulk + '{ "delete" : { "_index" : "' + str(result['_index']) + '", "_type" : "' + str(result['_type']) + '", "_id" : "' + str(result['_id']) + '" } }\n'
    # Finally do the deleting. 
    es.bulk( body=bulk )
```

To use the bulk api you need to ensure two things:

1. The document is identified You want to update. (index, type, id)
2. Each request is terminated with a newline or /n.

Answer (score 8):

The `elasticsearch-py` bulk API does allow you to delete records in bulk by including `'_op_type': 'delete'` in each record.  However, if you want to delete-by-query you still need to make two queries: one to fetch the records to be deleted, and another to delete them.

The easiest way to do this in bulk is to use python module's [`scan()`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html?highlight=delete#scan) helper, which wraps the ElasticSearch Scroll API so you don't have to keep track of `_scroll_id`s.  Use it with the [`bulk()`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html?highlight=delete#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk) helper as a replacement for the deprecated `delete_by_query()`:

```
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk, scan

bulk_deletes = []
for result in scan(es,
                   query=es_query_body,  # same as the search() body parameter
                   index=ES_INDEX,
                   doc_type=ES_DOC,
                   _source=False,
                   track_scores=False,
                   scroll='5m'):

    result['_op_type'] = 'delete'
    bulk_deletes.append(result)

bulk(elasticsearch, bulk_deletes)
```

---

Since `_source=False` is passed, the document body is not returned so each result is pretty small.  However, if do you have memory constraints, you can batch this pretty easily:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 100000

i = 0
bulk_deletes = []
for result in scan(...):

    if i == BATCH_SIZE:
        bulk(elasticsearch, bulk_deletes)
        bulk_deletes = []
        i = 0

    result['_op_type'] = 'delete'
    bulk_deletes.append(result)

    i += 1

bulk(elasticsearch, bulk_deletes)
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently using this script based on @drs response, but using [bulk()](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk) helper consistently. It has the ability to create batchs of jobs from a iterator by using `chunk_size` parameter (defaults to 500, see [straming_bulk()](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk) for more info).

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import scan, bulk

BULK_SIZE = 1000

def stream_items(es, query):
    for e in scan(es, 
                  query=query, 
                  index=ES_INDEX,
                  doc_type=ES_DOCTYPE, 
                  scroll='1m',
                  _source=False):

        # There exists a parameter to avoid this del statement (`track_source`) but at my version it doesn't exists.
        del e['_score']
        e['_op_type'] = 'delete'
        yield e

es = Elasticsearch(host='localhost')
bulk(es, stream_items(es, query), chunk_size=BULK_SIZE)
```

Answer (score 3):

While operationally equivalent to many other answers, I personally find the following syntax more accessible:

```py
import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk

es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(['localhost'])

ids = [1,2,3, ...]      # list of ids that will be deleted
index = "foo_index"     # index where the documents are indexed

actions = ({
    "_id": _id,
    "_op_type": "delete"
} for _id in ids)

bulk(client=es, actions=actions, index=index, refresh=True)
# `refresh=True` makes the result immediately available
```

Comment: Thank you, most other answers aren't as clear. This is the only one that was water clear.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, this was really useful!

I have two suggestions:

1. When getting the next page of results with scroll, `es.scroll(scroll_id=search['_scroll_id'])` should be the `_scroll_id` returned in the last scroll, not the one the search returned. Elasticsearch does not update the scroll ID every time, especially with smaller requests (see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997251/elasticsearch-scrolling-using-python-client)), so this code might work, but it's not foolproof.
2. It's important to clear scrolls as keeping search contexts open for a long time has a cost. [Clear Scroll API - Elasticsearch API documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#_clear_scroll_api) They will close eventually after timeout, but if you're low on disk space for example, it can save you a lot of headache.

An easy way is to build a list of scroll IDs on the go (make sure to get rid of duplicates!), and clear everything in the end.

```
es.clear_scroll(scroll_id=scroll_id_list)
```